# How to add code logic to Display Suite fields without PHP in Drupal 8? Twig?

Tags: theming, display-suite

Using Display Suite in Drupal 7 I can easily add PHP logic to any custom Display Suite Field. In Drupal 8 PHP is not allowed. How can I program logic in Display Suite fields in Drupal 8?

As an example, I'd like to use a simple if/then statement to show/hide a node field. I have tried embedding Twig into the field but it does not execute. It just renders as plain text.

This is my sample code `{# This is a test comment. #}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing hiding fields in twig is pretty simple. You can check if a field has a value like so:

```
{% if node.field_foo is not empty %}
  {{ content.field_foo }}
{% endif %}
```

You cannot execute raw PHP from a twig file, nor can you inject Twig and parse it out through field formatters (probably not without a lot of work, anyway).

***Note the difference between checking the node object and rendering the content array.***

You want to do checks against the entity object, and *never* (in my opinion) the render array. In the above code, if the field has a value, then the condition is true. If you want to *check* the value for a specific string, it is likely better suited for a preprocess hook.

What if the twig template being rendered is a Paragraph, and not a Node template? Not much difference:

```
{% if paragraph.field_foo is not empty %}
  {{ content.field_foo }}
{% endif %}
```

If you need more muscle, I would advise moving your logic to a preprocess hook in `mytheme.theme` where you can use whatever PHP you want, and inject new variables into your Twig file.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['show_foo_field'] = FALSE;

  // if field ...
  // and maybe some more conditions?
  $variables['show_foo_field'] = TRUE;
  // end if...
}
```

Then in the twig template...

```
{% if show_foo_field %}
  {{ content.field_foo }}
{% endif %}
```

Now, you say you are using Display Suite - I personally don't inject condition or code through the UI like what you are asking. But one thing I do know about [Display Suite is it (when I last looked) tends to hijack a majority of the preprocess calls](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/ds/tree/ds.module?h=8.x-3.x) - so check its docs or API for the right preprocess hook to call for nodes.

[The current hooks for Display suite can be viewed in its .api.php file](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/ds/tree/ds.api.php?h=8.x-3.x).

Definitely enable twig debug to be able to check what the Twig template naming pattern should be (suggestions) in the HTML source, and be aware of `mytheme_preprocess_node` potentially not firing. You will need to locate the correct DS hook.

Comment: I think the answer I needed  (although not the answer I wanted to hear) is that I cannot parse Twig through a field formatter.  Thanks for your additional, and comprehensive, advice.  I will check out the Display Suite API.

Comment: If you get a little lost in Display Suite, a good starting point is to setup a vanilla site without it and get a feel for theming under normal circumstances - then come back to Display Suite. When I first used it in 8.x, a lot of my preprocess hooks quit firing, and it threw me for a loop. Maybe you don't even need Display Suite - I find D8 theming easier than before.

Comment: I think you're right.  I may not even need DS in Drupal 8.  At least, not for theme logic.  It is still useful for overriding default field code and creating quick stacked layouts.

Comment: Yeah, it can be used for RAD/prototyping - just be aware that normal theme calls (namely preprocess) and template suggestions that are in the Drupal documentation _may not work_ when Display Suite is enabled. Just so you don't get confused later - it's not immediately clear at first without diving through the call stack and DS docs/code/api.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update: starting from its version 8.3.4, Display Suite supports "twig fields" as a new custom field type.
https://www.drupal.org/project/ds/issues/3072095